# Standing for Kaddish at a shul with a different nusach

Tags: sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, ashkenazi, kaddish, standing-sitting

It has already [been established](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9308/is-it-required-to-stand-during-kaddish) that Ashkenazim generally stand for Kaddish, while Sephardim sit unless they were already standing. (That said, I have observed Sephardim who *davka* sit for Kaddish.)

What should an Ashkenazi do in a Sephardi shul? Should one *davka* stand? On the other extreme, is it even permissible to go against the *minhag hamakom* of sitting? Conversely, should a Sephardi stand or sit for Kaddish when praying at an Ashkenazi shul?

Comment: There's probably room to do it either way.

Comment: @Tatpurusha so if my preference is to stand always, i should do that even when i find myself at a Sfardi shul? And if someone else likes to go with the _minhag hamakom_, that's also acceptable?

Comment: Let me put it to you this way: if you're in a synagogue that lays tefillin on chol ha-moed, and your custom is to not do so, or vice-versa, is it good to follow your own custom or the custom of the synagogue?

Comment: @Tatpurusha Hmm, i've never learned that halacha. :) Follow your own custom?

Comment: This is a very complicated issue. If you want my advice, ask the rav of the shul where you're going if he minds if you follow your own minhag. My instincts tell me that we are significantly less concerned today about minhag hamakom then we were even a hundred years ago, and so it should be fine to hold either way.

Comment: @Tatpurusha that seems good. Would you like to expand that into an answer?

Comment: I appreciate Tatpurusha's answer in light of the mixed qehillot we have today (e.g. Manhattan). Nevertheless, it would be good to have a source for his *shitah*.

Comment: @Lee and they are very common here in Israel. In fact, it is very difficult to find a minyan that only davens nusach Ashkenaz, or that even occasionally does. My shul generally davens nusach Sfard (not Edot Hamizrach), but with Ashkenazi tunes and customs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Qitzur Shulhhan Arukh - Yalqut Yosef, Siman 56:11](http://www.ateret4u.com/online/f_01355_part_4.html#%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%9FB%D7%A0%D7%95B-B%D7%93%D7%99%D7%9FB%D7%A2%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%99%D7%AAB%D7%94%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%99%D7%A9B%D7%A2%D7%9CB%D7%99%D7%93%D7%99B%D7%94%D7%A7%D7%94%D7%9C,B%D7%95%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%93B%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%99B%D7%94%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%99%D7%A9-%D7%99%D7%90) writes (my translation):

> מנהג האשכנזים כדעת הרמ''א, לעמוד בשעה שעונים קדיש וברכו, וספרדי שמתפלל עם אשכנזים, נכון שיעמוד גם הוא עמהם בעת אמירת קדיש וברכו, כדי שלא יהיה בכלל יושב בין העומדים.
>
> The Ashkenazi custom, per the ReM"A, is to stand when responding to Qaddish and Barekhu. And, as for a Sepharadi praying with Ashkenazim, it is proper for him to also stand with them when responding to Qaddish and Barekhu, so as not to sit among those standing.

My $0.02: Perhaps Hakham 'Ovadiah is poseq this way since standing among those sitting or sitting amongst those standing could cause Mahhloqet. Again, that interpretation is mine and he does not write that explicitly. He simply writes "so as not to sit among those standing".

Rav Chaim (Howard) Jachter rules similarly (in "[Sephardic and Ashkenazic Practice: Do You Sit or Stand for Kaddish?](http://bcjlink.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=4132:sephardic-and-ashkenazic-practice-do-you-sit-or-stand-for-kaddish&catid=150:news&Itemid=562)") for an Ashkenazi praying amidst Sepharadim (i.e. that one should follow Minhag HaMaqom):

> In addition to conforming to Minhag HaMakom (which, in general, is the
> proper practice – see Mishnah Pesahim 4:1) it seems disrespectful to Hashem if one
> would exclude himself from a Kehillah which is standing in honor of Hashem.
> **Conversely, it seems appropriate for an Ashkenazi praying at a Sephardic synagogue to
> follow the custom of the Kehillah to remain seated for Kaddish**.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, i only find this addresses half of my question. What would an Ashkenazi do in a Sfardi shul?

Comment: Added publication from Rav Chaim Jachter for Ashkenazi amidst Sepharadim

Comment: I can't seem to find any additional reference to the hyperlink included of Rav Jachter's publication. This worries me a bit and makes me questions its authenticity. Can anyone validate?

Comment: I've updated the Rav Jachter source to a more reliable one (the "Jewish Link of Bergen County" archive). It appears he did, in fact, rule in accordance with the bolded text in my answer.